# In perl delete a specific lines from a file

Tags: perl

I want to delete the the line with HPOM, and keep only the line node:

my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

open (FILE, "/tmp/agentstas.dat");

my @lines = <FILE>;

my $lines;

my $string = "Node";

my $badstring = "hpom";

foreach $lines (@lines) {

    if ($lines =~ $string || $lines !=~ $badstring)  { print "$lines"; }

}
```

the results:

```
Node atum1:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node vmatum3:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node ls_sfda-new:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node risto4:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node jzn18z1:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node sqlcatom:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node new-sspc-as:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node dafna:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node adonis:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node hydra:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node kukuad:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node janus1:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node janus2:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node zubin.extranet.gov.il:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node nyx-as:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node keto1:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node sql12ao1:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node keto2:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node durge:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node vcmanage:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node vcmobile:
Node vishnu:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node ram:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node brizo.iaadom:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node krishna:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node mars1:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node mars2:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node rasas:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node hypons.iaadom:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node nnm-as.iaadom:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node risto3:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node ivrmanage.iaadom:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node mpsair01:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node mpsland01:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node atum2.iaadom:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node vmatum4.iaadom:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node rastas:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node nnm-ls.iaadom:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node rasls:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node ask1:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node ask2:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node grid2:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node grid1:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node ivrdb:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node dafn:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node mist1:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node mist2:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node amun:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node amun1:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node dagon:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node dagon1:
Node davlin2:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node cet:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node sdns:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node pdns:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node hermes1.iaadom:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node tyr2:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node tyr1:
HPOM Managed Node status :
Node new_sspcls:
Node hapy1:
Node geb:
Node saga:
Node indra:
Node yama:
```

Comment: You have added a second question to your question. Please don't - asking questions is free, ask a separate one. (Which doesn't invalidate existing answers).

Comment: I have rolled back to the version before the massive re-edit. Please accept one of the answers below, so as to prevent this question from showing up as unresolved, and post a new question if you need help with a different problem. (Do provide a link back here if it makes sense for context.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always use three arguments and lexical filehandle to perform a file operation.
If you want delete all the lines start from 'HPOM', you can write your code as:

```
open my $fh, "<", "/tmp/agentstas.dat" or die $!;

my @lines = <$fh>;

foreach my $lines (@lines)
{
    next if ($lines =~ m/^HPOM/i);
    print "$lines";
}
```

Or better use a `while loop`:

```
while (my $lines = <$fh>)
{
    chomp $lines;
    next if ($lines =~ m/^HPOM/i);
    print "$lines\n";
}
```

Or in your code change this line:

```
if ($lines =~ $string || $lines !=~ $badstring)  { print "$lines"; }
```

to

```
if ($lines =~ /^$string/i || $lines !~ /^$badstring/i)  { print "$lines"; }
```

`^` = matching the start of the string.
`i` = Do case-insensitive pattern matching.

`i` because you have taken `$badstring` in small letters and in input file it is in capital letters.

Comment: Maybe also explain why a `while` loop is much better -- it only keeps one line in memory at a time, instead of reading the whole file into memory and then trickling it back out.

Comment: Why `chomp()` if you're just going to add the newline back in the `print()`?

Comment: Just showed, in case OP is going to do some other operation instead of direct printing.

Comment: Although technically valid, it's confusing to have a scalar `$lines` and an array `@lines`, especially when `$lines` only contains one line!

Answer (score 3):

Hard-coding a filename is often a bad idea. Your programs are more flexible if you use the Unix filter model (read from STDIN, write to STDOUT).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

while (<>) {
  print unless /^HPOM/;
}
```

Run it as:

```
$ ./your_filter.pl < /tmp/agentstas.dat > output_file
```

Comment: Well, I guess he could even do something like `map { print unless /^HPOM/ } <>` then, if he wanted a one-liner :-)

Comment: Using `map` in void context isn't a good idea. Perhaps you wanted `print grep { ! /^HPOM/ } <>` :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your initial code is far too complicated. Try this instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings; 

open (my $input, '<', "/tmp/agentstas.dat") or die $!;

while ( <$input> ) {
   print if m/^Node/i;
}
close ( $input );
```

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. The bug is in the `if` condition.

```
if ($lines =~ $string || $lines !=~ $badstring)
```

should be

```
if ($lines =~ $string && $lines !=~ $badstring)
```

because you want **both** conditions to be true (AND, not OR).

Using perl's `-n` switch we can solve this as a nice one-liner:

```
$ perl -ne '/Node/ && ! /hpom/ && print' /tmp/agentstas.dat
```

You don't even have to use perl, you can just use

```
$ grep -e ^Node /tmp/agentstas.dat
```

to only list lines beginning with "Node" (which seems to be what you are trying to achieve).